# Spotify App-Remote Integration in FireTV Android

Tags: java, android, spotify, amazon-fire-tv

I'm implementing the Spotify App-Remote integration into my FireTV App so that I can use the audio playback feature.

I have downloaded the Spotify application onto the FireTV device so that the integration can work with my FireTV application.

However, I am getting the error below;

> com.spotify.android.appremote.api.error.CouldNotFindSpotifyApp error

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

I followed all the steps and [documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/android/quick-start/) presented by Spotify.

Here is my code;

```
private static final String CLIENT_ID = "my_client_id";
private static final String REDIRECT_URI = "http://com.mydomain.myapp/callback";
private SpotifyAppRemote mSpotifyAppRemote;
private ConnectionParams connectionParams;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
 setConnectionParams();
}
private void setConnectionParams() {
 connectionParams = new ConnectionParams.Builder(CLIENT_ID)
  .setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI)
  .showAuthView(true)
  .build();
}
@Override
protected void onStart() {
 super.onStart();
 setConnectionParams();
 SpotifyAppRemote.connect(this, connectionParams, new Connector.ConnectionListener() {
  @Override
  public void onConnected(SpotifyAppRemote spotifyAppRemote) {
   mSpotifyAppRemote = spotifyAppRemote;
   connected();
  }

  @Override
  public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
   Log.e("SPOT", "Failed", throwable);
  }
 });
}

private void connected() {
 mSpotifyAppRemote.getPlayerApi().play("spotify:playlist:someRandomId");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Currently there is no way to use the Spotify App-Remote integration on FireTV. Here's the [link](http://github.com/spotify/android-sdk/issues/186) to the issue and answer from a Spotify contributor